# regex seems to be off for special characters (e.g. +-.,!@#$%^&*;)

Tags: java, regex, debugging, limit

I am using regex to print out a string and adding a new line after a character limit. I don't want to split up a word if it hits the limit (start printing the word on the next line) unless a group of concatenated characters exceed the limit where then I just continue the end of the word on the next line. However when I hit special characters(e.g. +-.,!@#$%^&*;) as you'll see when I test my code below, it adds an additional character to the limit for some reason. Why is this?

My function is:

```
public static String limiter(String str, int lim) {
    str = str.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
    str = str.replaceAll("\n +", "\n");
    Matcher mtr = Pattern.compile("(.{1," + lim + "}(\\W|$))|(.{0," + lim + "})").matcher(str);
    String newStr = "";
    int ctr = 0;
    while (mtr.find()) {
        if (ctr == 0) {
            newStr += (mtr.group());
            ctr++;
        } else {
            newStr += ("\n") + (mtr.group());
        }
    }
    return newStr ;
}
```

So my input is: 
`String str = "     The   123456789  456789 +-.,!@#$%^&*();\\/|<>\"\'  fox     jumpeded     over the uf\n 2   3456 green     fence     ";`

With a character line limit of 7.

It outputs:

```
456789 +
-.,!@#$%
^&*();\/
|<>"
```

When the correct output should be:

```
456789
+-.,!@#
$%^&*()
;\/|<>"
```

My code is linked to an online compiler you can run here:
https://ideone.com/9gckP1

Comment: Are you missing a comma in `{0" + lim + "})"`? i.e. shouldn't it be `{0," + lim + "})"`?

Comment: I guess you need to [replace `(\W|$)` with `\b`](https://ideone.com/eqcNzW) and you forgot a comma with `(.{0" + lim + "})`.

Comment: @stribizhev that fixes it mostly, but when I run it, it adds a space before "+" for some reason which I don't want :/

Comment: What about [this fix](https://ideone.com/NHlbLf)? I added `\s*` to trim the end of each newly created line.

Comment: whoa nice, so it was adding the " \\s* " and " (?U) ". What does the (?U) do?

Comment: `(?U)` is just to "fix" `\b` behavior with Unicode strings. Does my code work as expected?

Comment: Yes i does! and I wish you could write it in the answer section so I can accept it! :) Oh and also upvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the `(\W|$)` with `\b` as your intention is to match whole words (and `\b` provides this functionality). Also, since you do not need trailing whitespace on newly created lines, you need to also use `\s*`.

So, use

```
Matcher mtr = Pattern.compile("(?U)(.{1," + lim + "}\\b\\s*)|(.{0," + lim + "})").matcher(str);
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/NHlbLf)

Note that `(?U)` is used here to "fix" the word boundary behavior to keep it in sync with `\w` (so that diacritics were not considered word characters).

Comment: you rock dude, hmm so I tested it without the (?U) and it still works as expected

Comment: Yes, I also learnt that some days ago and the impact of not using `(?U)` is very small (perhaps, it won't even have any if your input does not contain precomposed characters), it is just there to "make things right".

Comment: Got it, appreciate your help regex jedi

Answer (score 1):

In your pattern, `\\W` is part of the first capturing group. It is adding this one (non-word) character to the `.{1,limit}` pattern.

Try with: "(.{1," + lim + "})(\W|$)|(.{0," + lim + "})"

(I can't currently use your regex online compiler)

Comment: So I fixed a typo for it to be .{0,limit}, but now I get an extra space before "+" which I don't want :/

Comment: That doesn't work either it give me the same output, a commenter found the bug fix XD thanks though